# Compiling QTermWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

I've tried to compile [this custom QT widget to provide a terminal that I can embed into my application.](https://github.com/lxde/qtermwidget) I've compiled/installed [the build tools for the program](https://github.com/lxde/lxqt-build-tools) that I needed before Cmake would complete, but the make step is throwing errors that google hasn't been too helpful on:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/qtermwidget5.dir/lib/kpty.cpp.o
/Users/a7c/qtermwidget/qtermwidget-master/lib/kpty.cpp:506:26: error: no member named 'ut_name' in 'utmpx'
        strncpy(l_struct.ut_name, user, sizeof(l_struct.ut_name));
                ~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/a7c/qtermwidget/qtermwidget-master/lib/kpty.cpp:506:57: error: no member named 'ut_name' in 'utmpx'
        strncpy(l_struct.ut_name, user, sizeof(l_struct.ut_name));
                                               ~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/a7c/qtermwidget/qtermwidget-master/lib/kpty.cpp:617:20: error: no member named 'ut_name' in 'utmpx'
        memset(ut->ut_name, 0, sizeof(*ut->ut_name));
               ~~  ^
/Users/a7c/qtermwidget/qtermwidget-master/lib/kpty.cpp:617:44: error: no member named 'ut_name' in 'utmpx'
        memset(ut->ut_name, 0, sizeof(*ut->ut_name));
                                       ~~  ^
4 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/qtermwidget5.dir/lib/kpty.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/qtermwidget5.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

And as an extension, how exactly does one effectively include a custom widget as to be usable in QT Creator?

Comment: What version of Qt do you have and what is your OS?

Comment: @eyllanesc The OS is Mac OSX El Capitain (10.11 i believe?), and QT 5.8

Comment: What is target machine for this project?

Comment: Be advised to check out is there mismatch between the version of GCC for application building the one used for the sysroot.

Answer (score 4):

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/utmpx.h.html

It looks like it doesn't include `ut_name` in the stock version of utmpx.h.

If you look at this version of it:

https://code.woboq.org/kde/include/bits/utmp.h.html

They have a "backwards compatibility hack" in there:

```
87  /* Backwards compatibility hacks.  */
88  #define ut_name     ut_user
```

You may want to upgrade that library that includes that header. Or just insert that `#define` in your code.  And as a good github citizen, if it works, you should do a pull request and/or submit an issue about it so that the next person using that library doesn't run into the same issue.

Hope that helps.

Comment: utmpx.h is readonly - even with sudo. How do I update it? I dont even know what library it is a part of. Thank you for you help so far though.

Comment: Actually, the default Mac utmpx.h file has `#define ut_user ut_name`

Comment: Then that means that you have another one in your path that your compiler is finding before this one.  Try a `locate utmpx.h` command on the terminal, and then add that path into your include paths in your .pro file.

Comment: I'm stuck on compiling the widget - I haven't managed to get to anything with .pro files, or putting the widget into my application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know *why* the problem happened, since according to all the files I checked everything was named properly.

Adding `#define ut_user ut_name` to kpty.h solved the problem though.